# java.io.NotSerializableException in a predefined jar : barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar

Tags: java, jasper-reports, barbecue

I'm using JasperReport library and barbecue api to fill a report containing an UCC128 bar code, but when i execute the code i'm getting this error but i don't even have a starting point to solve this problem :

> Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: net.sourceforge.barbecue.linear.code128.CharBuffer
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.writeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:710)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSwapFileVirtualizer.pageOut(JRSwapFileVirtualizer.java:87)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.virtualizeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:664)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.evict(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:485)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.requestData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:630)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.ensureData(VirtualizableElementList.java:463)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.ensureDataAndTouch(VirtualizableElementList.java:432)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.get(VirtualizableElementList.java:283)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.VirtualizableElementList.get(VirtualizableElementList.java:96)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.VirtualizableElementList.get(VirtualizableElementList.java:54)
>       at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:834)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:818)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:695)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:417)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:150)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:497)
>       at fr.srd.remap.runtime.PdfReportGenerator.generate(PdfReportGenerator.java:124)
>       at fr.srd.remap.runtime.Main.main(Main.java:89)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: net.sourceforge.barbecue.linear.code128.CharBuffer
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:962)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.writeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:704)
>       ... 18 more